# Formating java Date with java.time.DateTimeFormatter including time offset

Tags: java, datetime-format, garbage

I am currently struggling to refactor this piece of old code to use the new `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` because it is used in our main logging component where this creates unnecessary garbage.

```
private String getFormattedDate(final Date date) {
    // a new instance is created foreach log message 
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

I already tried the new ISO_INSTANT formater like:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(date.toInstant());
```

but this gives (slightly) different output as before.

My test shows:

```
Expected: is "2013-10-22T05:23:48.397+0200"
 but: was "2013-10-22T03:23:48.397Z"
```

So I need the time zone offset to be included in the format string as shown in Expected.

I know about the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` but I didnt manage to build it in a way to get my desired format output.

How would I need to do this?
I know I can always fall back to using a single thread local SimpleDateFormat instance but I would like to use the new java.time stuff :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Date date = new Date();

System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(date.toInstant()));
// output: 2015-11-22T14:46:08.776Z

System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.format(
       date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())));
// output: 2015-11-22T15:46:08.776+01:00

System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME
                                    .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                                    .format(date.toInstant()));
// output: 2015-11-22T15:46:08.776+01:00
```